# Single setup step in Locust 1.6.0?

Tags: python-3.x, api, performance-testing, load-testing, locust

I have been trying out how to setup a resource only once and share with user that gets created with locust

This is what I have been trying:

```
from locust import HttpUser
from locust.user.task import task

class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    def setup(self):
        client = clients.HttpSession(base_url=self.host)
        token = client.post("get-token/", {'email': 'someemail', 'password': 'somepassword'})
        client.headers.update(
            {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        )
    tasks = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 500
    max_wait = 900
```

As you see I wanted to fetch the token for once and share this with all other user instances that are created while load testing.
I can't figure out a way to achieve this.
Any sort of help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to save the token in a variable accessible outside of the `User` to make it accessible by all users, otherwise each user would create its own.

```
from locust import HttpUser
from locust.user.task import task

token = ''

class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    def setup(self):
        global token
        client = clients.HttpSession(base_url=self.host)
        token = client.post("get-token/", {'email': 'someemail', 'password': 'somepassword'})
        client.headers.update(
            {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        )
    tasks = UserBehavior
    min_wait = 500
    max_wait = 900
```

I'm not positive but you might also need to set the headers before each request instead of setting them once.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
This was the last resort I opted and I did follow the approach of setting a global token eventually.

I just wanted to know if there is a standard way of doing it.
Cause I wasn't sure if this is the best way

Comment: A slightly nicer solution is using a class level variable (e.g. WebsiteUser.token)

Comment: That's fair, assuming there's only the one class you want to access it from.